# Adding nested attributes to devise user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attributes, devise, nested

At first glance it would seem this question has been answered before, but not on my case (most are related to mass assignment issues and/or mongoid.) I have not been able to find an answer even though there are plenty somewhat related questions here.

So basically I'm using the devise gem for user authentication on a ruby on rails application and I want to add a nested address model to the user model. I'm also using simple_form to generate the form views.

I have a user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
  has_one :address

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

This is the address model:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :state
  belongs_to :user

  attr_accessible :street1, :street2, :country_id, :state_id, :city, :postalCode
end
```

This is the Users controller, which I overrode in order to add a show action to display user profile.

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    resource = build_resource({})
    resource.build_address
    respond_with resource
  end

  # POST /resource
  def create
    resource = build_resource(params[:user])

    if resource.save
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    #Add to view count if not viewing own user profile
    if @user != current_user
      @user.views += 1
      @user.save  
    end

    @vehicles = Vehicle.where(:user_id => @user)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end
end
```

This is the view for creating new users:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name) ) do |f| %>

              <fieldset>
                    <%= f.input :username, :required => false, :autofocus => true, placeholder: 'Pick a username' %>
                    <%= f.input :email, :required => false, placeholder: 'Your email' %>
                    <%= f.input :password, :required => false, placeholder: 'Create a password' %>
                    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :required => false, placeholder: 'Confirm your password' %>
                    <%= f.association :roles, :as => :check_boxes, :label => "", :required => false %>
                    <%= f.simple_fields_for :address do |a| %>
                        <%= a.input :street1 %>
                        <%= a.input :street2 %>
                        <%= a.association :country %>
                        <%= a.association :state %>
                        <%= a.input :city %>
                        <%= a.input :postalCode %>
                    <% end %>
                    <%= f.button :submit, 'Sign up for free', :class => 'btn btn-success btn-large' %>
              </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

**So the error upon creating a new user is this:
Address user can't be blank**

Basically the foreign key user_id is not being set for address.

I was hoping somebody can shed a little light on this issue.

Comment: have you tried setting `:inverse_of` for user and address relation?

Comment: another way you could ensure `user_id` gets set is to `@address = @user.build_address` in the `UsersController#new` action and then in the form use `@address` as the object for the nested form. Keeping in mind that you'll be creating an address for every user no mater what.

Comment: Hi Andy! I took into account both suggestions. :inverse_of did nothing, same issue. Then I changed new action and view fields for as suggested and now I get the following exception: ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in Users::RegistrationsController#create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to add user_id to address migration. Rails expected it when adding belongs_to :user to the address model.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this in my application, but I am using strong parameters. However the solution should still be applicable in your case.

Instead of overriding all of the methods in the `RegistrationsController` I just overrode `build_resource` to pass in the correct parameters needed.

```
def build_resource(params)
  super(resource_params)
end

def resource_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, tickets_attributes: [ :description ] )
end
```

I also have the `inverse_of` on my `User` and `Ticket` models, Like this:

```
user.rb
  has_many :tickets, inverse_of: :user

ticket.rb
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of :tickets
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, I never got this to work, I'll try your solution and report back as soon as I can.  Thank you for suggesting a solution.